# Merge posts and post metadata of two wordpress databases

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I have developed a new theme for my [Android-Blog](http://www.1a-android.de).
To do so I created a copy of it's database at my local machine and set up a development environment.

During developing I added and changed posts of that development-database, and of course in the live-system changes were made too.

My goal is now to keep the latest version of every post, while merging both databses. Id collision conflicts have to be resolved. The post meta-data table and the comments table must be altered within the merging process. The comments of the development database should be dropped. The comments should be taken from the productive-system but they of course must refer to their correct counterpart post.

**Here comes the question:**
Is there a tool, that supports me with the merging process, or do I have to really write my own database merger?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WP CLI tool to export data from your development environment. Then just use wordpress import tool to import the posts. You have to be on a UNIX system to use wp cli tool.

http://wp-cli.org/

Comment: I am but how is it going to merge asynchronously changed data?
E.g. one of the articles still exist in an older version at the installation to which I import.

Maybe it's at least worth giving a try on a backup system.

Comment: It is better to keep the databases between prod and dev synced as much   as possible. Merging changed posts seems like a good way to get mysterious problems.